# Vue.js data not updating when receiving message from socket

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket

I'm trying to design a vue.js app that updates data about the state of a game upon receiving a "new_state" message from a socket. The socket is implemented using django channels.

This is what the code looks like:

```
const ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws"

const gameSocket = new WebSocket(
    ws_scheme +
    '://'
    + window.location.host
    + '/ws/play/'
    + game_id
    + '/'
)
    let vue = new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        data: {
            current_turn: 0,
            last_turn: -1,
            current_card: 0,
            last_card: -1,
            number_of_stacked_cards: 0,
            last_amount_played: 0,
            won_by: -1,
            my_cards: [],
            other_players_data: {},
        },

        created() {
            gameSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
                data = JSON.parse(e.data)
                this.current_turn = data.state.current_turn
                this.last_turn = data.state.last_turn
               // ... update the other data
            };
        },
    });
```

When I receive the message, logging the data makes it apparent that I'm receiving correct information. However, if I go and type `vue.current_turn` after receiving the message, it's still `0` instead of the new value; same for all the other members of the `data` object.
I tried with `vue.current_turn = data.state.current_turn` and it does work this way, but obviously it should work with `this`.

What's wrong with my code?

And generally speaking, what's the best way of accomplishing what I'm after, i.e. updating internal data variables upon receiving messages from a socket?

I have to do with without using the socket.io library, which isn't supported by channels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `this` is pointing to whatever calls `gameSocket.onmessage`, not the "normal Vue `this`".

To get around the issue you could do `let self = this` above `gameSocket.onmessage` and use `self` inside of it.

Comment: thank you! this is so obvious, yet somehow I missed it. Regarding my general approach to update object state from socket message, is the one I'm using the best way to do it or is there anything better I can do?

Comment: No problem, it happens to all of us :) Yes, I think the general approach you're using to update the state is fine. You could modularize it if you'd like, having a separate function to do the update and then breaking that function into subfunctions for code clarity purposes.  Eg. `updateMessage(dataFromSocket)` and then break that into `updateThisPartOfTheMessage` and `updateThatPartOfTheMessage`. But that's nothing specific to Vue, just the general programming practice of modularity. In a Vue component these functions would be in [`methods`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods)

Comment: Sure thing. Good luck!

Comment: I was completely baffled as to why my var wasn't updating after receiving data via a socket emit and while my code is slightly different, this absolutely worked and I too had overlooked that "this" was pointing to the socket instead.. Thanks @AdamZerner

Comment: Same issue for me... I was assigning a variable within the socket `onmessage` and not in my the data block.... ughhhh..... Thank you so much, @AdamZerner!